# Selecting data from different rows in the same table with a single statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm selecting data from two different rows in the same table using a single sql.

```
"id"    "borrowMax" "holder"    "category"  "country"
"1"     "2"         "0"         "3"         "US"
"2"     "0"         "1"         "10"        "US"
```

What I'm trying to do works out to this.

```
select id, holder from mytable where id = 2
select borrowMax from mytable where id = (
        holder from the above select, in this case it's 1
) and category = 3
```

**The way I do it after looking at examples online is**

```
SELECT col1.id, col1.holder, col2.borrowMax
FROM collection_db col1
JOIN collection_db col2
ON col2.holder = col1.id
WHERE col1.id = 2 //Here, 2 is the value supplied by me
AND col2.category = 3
```

Sure, this works. But since it's something I pieced together myself, I have my doubts. How would `you` do something like this? Am I on the right track? (I'm sure I'm not).

Comment: looks ok to me - and if it gives you the results you want then it should be good.

Comment: @IanKenney I had doubts regarding the `JOIN`. Should it be `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: `JOIN` is OK: when you specify the `ON ...` condition, `JOIN` is equivalent to  `INNER JOIN`. It's more or less explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make use of nested select statements for a use case like yours. There is no JOIN operation being used, just a select query over a already filtered set of results and a logically more coherent code.

```
SELECT borrowmax, holder, id FROM mytable WHERE 
  id = (SELECT holder FROM mytable WHERE id = 2 )
    AND category = 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use table alias for this.

```
select t1.id, t1.holder, t2.borrowMax from mytable t1, mytable t2 where t1.id = t2.holder
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to find What is the difference in population between 2000 and 2010 in Indonesia?
Table columns:

```
country STRING
population  NUMBER
year    NUMBER
```

This is the query that gave me the result I was looking for:

```
SELECT b.country,
(b.population - a.population) 
AS diff_population
  FROM population_years a
  JOIN population_years b ON b.country = a.country
WHERE b.country = 'Indonesia'
  AND a.year = 2000
  AND b.year = 2010;
```